# How to add element to queue

Tags: c, queue

I really can't understand what's wrong with my code.

Everything is fine when I add first element but after that, it's not working. When ptr is NULL it enters while loop.
Is there a problem on checking if null?

```
struct Car
{
    int startTime;
    char *model;
    char *code;
    char *location;
    struct Car *next;
    int deptEnterTime;
    bool waitingForFraming;
    bool waitingForPainting;
    bool waitingForPolishing;
    bool waitingForEngine;
    bool waitingForElectronic;
    bool waitingForIndoor;
    bool waitingForTest;
};

struct Car *head = NULL;
void insert(int startTime, char *model, char *code)
{
    /*create a link*/
    struct Car *link = (struct Car*) malloc(sizeof(struct Car));

    link->startTime= startTime;
    link->model = model;
    link->code = code;
    link->waitingForFraming=true;
    link->waitingForPainting=false;
    link->waitingForPolishing=false;
    link->waitingForEngine=false;
    link->waitingForElectronic=false;
    link->waitingForIndoor=false;
    link->waitingForTest=false;

    if(head == NULL)
    {
        head = link;
    }
    else
    {
        struct Car *ptr;
        ptr = head->next;

        while(ptr != NULL)
        {
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
        ptr = link;

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters you have to set the data member `next` to NULL for the added element.

```
struct Car *link = (struct Car*) malloc(sizeof(struct Car));

link->next = NULL;
//...
```

This part of the function is also wrong

```
else
{
    struct Car *ptr;
    ptr = head->next;

    while(ptr != NULL)
    {
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    ptr = link;

}
```

It should be written like

```
else
{
    struct Car *ptr = head;

    while( ptr->next != NULL)
    {
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    ptr->next = link;

}
```

Take into account that if you are going to add elements to the end of the list then you should declare at least a two-sided list. Otherwise adding elements to the end of the list is inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

You should assign it to last usable structure not next one, here's how you could do it:

```
struct Car *ptr = head;
while(ptr->next != NULL)
{
    ptr = ptr->next;
}
ptr->next = link;
```

And I would suggest to set link->next to NULL to avoid random data there:

```
....
link->waitingForTest=false;
link->next=NULL;

if(head == NULL)
.....
```